# How to describe the generic parameters of a map where the key is a property of the value?

Tags: typescript

How can one specify the generic parameters of a `Map` such that the each key is mapped to a value that contains the key as a value for the specific property. If that's not clear, here is an example:

```
const example = {
  'a': {
    specialKey: 'a',
    aField: 'specific thing to a'
  },
  'b': {
    specialKey: 'b',
    bField: 'specific thing to b'
  }
}
```

In the above example, I want to capture that for the value for key `a`, `specialKey` has value `a`.

Comment: why is it important that the type make this distinction? If you know that the value for `specialKey` will match the key in the `example` object then that should be enough for whatever your use case is

Comment: Because I'm accepting an type as a generic parameter and I want to ensure that the type specified has the above property.

Comment: The example muddies the constraints in your question. Do you literally want a prop in each object which follows the pattern `${key}Field` of type `string`?

Comment: I don't care about `aField` and `bField`. I care that `specialKey` is 'a' and 'b' respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an identity function to enforce the kind of key-value type relationship described in your question.

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=29&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABANwIYBsYBMCyqAOiAPACqICmAHlOWFgM6IDeAUIogNoDSiMSA1uQCecYIhIBdAFyIeVGnUb0oAJz4BzRAH5mievnIQYGLsJk8AvohlhyycioDcLCwD5EACjToQ5GSQBKf2Y2RBVyKBAVJG9fZwsWFggEZUQAWwIARkQAXhQMbDx8D1Z2VBlS9j0DIxMzRAByVAaAGlCLNvYAIwrQ9n1DY3RTIRkGrta+vVUNAAUVOHwx4Dg4SarEMBA0rod5xZkAFgAmTsQOlwDnJJSodIJj3PzMXAIS0PKQjYHa4fqm9bnM49L5VH5DEZjCCTAD0MPYAD0kciUSw4eIhAZGgAiCDYhq8RhgOB3VD0egwdRgVBddDkRBQOAMzH0hrYrr4gB0HmOAGZjscAlNlGowOp9ktGis1md2FsdnsFpKTmcLhYriwgA)

```ts
function validMap <T extends {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends string ? { specialKey: K } : never;
}> (value: T): T {
  return value;
}

const map1 = validMap({
  a: {
    specialKey: 'a',
  },
  b: {
    specialKey: 'b',
    stringProp: 'foo',
    numberProp: 42,
  },
});

const map2 = validMap({
  a: {
    specialKey: 'a',
  },
  b: {
    specialKey: 'c',
//  ^^^^^^^^^^
// Type '"c"' is not assignable to type '"b"'.(2322)
    stringProp: 'foo',
    numberProp: 42,
  },
});
```